# Why do I always get NSURLConnection timeouts when downloading images over cellular networks?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, 3g

My app appears to work terribly over cellular networks - the UI often has spinners instead of images, but not always. It uses NSURLConnections driven by concurrent NSOperations. It works fine on WIFI - no problems at all.

I discovered I'm getting many NSURLConnection timeouts, but have no idea why. How can I track this problem down?

Answer (score 7):

To track down the problem, I first measured the maximum number of concurrent connections, and discovered that this was consistently around 55.

- reduced the maximum to 10 (by setting the operation queue max value, less timeouts, but still not perfect
- reduced the maximum to 4 - even less timeouts but still got some
- set the maximum to 1 - this has got to work, right? Nope!

Sometimes the app would work properly with no concurrency at all (max == 1), but it still failed about half the time.

So I burned a support incident with Apple and got one of there most experienced engineers to advise. Based on suggestions from him I tried the following:

- ran the app on a different carrier's cellular network (Verizon), and it worked perfectly. So the issue was not cellular per se (or iOS) but AT&T's cellular network (NY and NJ both fail)
- switched from http to https, now it works flawless on AT&T with full concurrency
- investigated the web endpoint to determine its capabilities, which turned out to be pretty poor (more later). I tried a different web endpoint with more capabilities, and the original problem went away using http.

What I learned from this was as follows:

- there was no difference using iOS5.1 or iOS6
- if you have this problem on AT&T 3G and are using http, try switching to https
- if the endpoint is using HTTP1.0 and does NOT support 'Connection: keep-alive', then every http request is setting up and tearing down a TCP connection. I believe this 'thrashing' of the cellular network is why AT&T was disconnecting some of my sessions, but of course have no way to know this for sure.
- using a HTTP1.1 service that supports persistent connections, the problem disappeared. In this case there is no TCP connection thrashing.
- some HTTP1.1 services support 'pipelining', as does iOS (using the NSURLRequest setting, HTTPShouldUsePipelining), and if I can switch to this then my performance should greatly improve
- there is a WWDC 2012 video that discusses how to improve network performance: Session 706 "Networking Best Practices"

EDIT

So this just gets more bizarre as I peel the onion! After further discussion, some web people did a test with CloudFront, and it did accept 'Connection: keep-alive'. I tried over and over to get it to work yesterday, but could not.

The web expert suggest I try it when using https and low and behold it did! For some reason, when using 'http' over AT&T 3G, that header tag is either removed or ignored. I tested my app with Wifi too. In all cases but AT&T/3G the 'Connection' was returned in the response.