# Using cellular data crashes application when using NSUrl + NSData

Tags: ios, wifi, 3g, cellular-network

I have an application made in Swift that uses NSUrl and NSData to get a JSON response from an API.

If I am on cellular data, the app closes as soon as it tries to make the connection. On WiFi (or the emulator) it is fine.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109874/nsurlconnection-ios-3g-issue) article which seems to show there might be a bug, but its not based in Swift and it's not using the same components.

How can I set the "setAllowCellularAccess" option in my application?

My code:

```
let loginUrl = "<my server URL>"
var message  :String
var success : Int
var endPoint = NSUrl(string: loginUrl + username + "/" + password)
var data = NSData(contentsOfUrl: endPoint!)
```

Comment: What do you mean by app closes. Is it crashes? what is the error you are getting? have you tried to debug?

Comment: On the iPad, on 3G data, it simply closes. No error popups or anything. I can't debug via the emulator, so I'll try find a cable to get the iPad hooked up..

Comment: Just debug by connecting your device with mac, check console log in Xcode by setting "All Exception breakpoint"

Comment: Hmm, looks like the iPad I have on hand currently (a clients) has an older version of iOS that I can'y use with XCode :/ Regardless, have you any idea how to fix the issue? I'm sure I need to set the "setAllowCellularAccess" option, but I don't know how

Comment: When debugging, I get a message about turning on cellular data, but that doesn't seem to show up when installing from the App Store...